# Is it an SEO problem to link to short URLs that redirect to canonical URLs but put the canonical URLs in the sitemap?

Tags: seo, redirects, sitemap, canonical-url

I have a URL that I have added to my sitemap that reflects a health-tip entity

> `http://www.example.com/health-tips/232344/this-is-perfect-for-your-health`

where `232344` is the id of the entity.

Though, the links to this entity throughout the website are as follows :

`<a href="http://www.example.com/health-tips/232344/"> Go to the perfect tip </a>`

When the link is clicked, the application processes the id in the URL, adds the proper title and redirects to the same page again with title added in the URL.

Does this cause any problem with crawling by SE? Shall I add the URL with title as canonical URL in the page of the health-tip? Shall I use the full URL with the title in the `href`?

Comment: It would be better if each link URL is complete. You would get better semantic value for it. As well, it would be better not to redirect links to other pages. While there is nothing technically wrong with this, it is a waste of resources for both the client and server. As well, it can be seen as potentially being suspect if all of your links redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest updating the links in your website to the absolute URL and avoid redirections (unless of course you have valuable links pointing to the URL ending with the ID)

This is an unnecessary redirection and should better be avoided.